# Sending a message to a remote terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, unix-shell

Is there a way to send a message to a remote terminal similar to using the wall command for other users on the local system?  In this scenario I want to specify a username@hostname and have a message appear in their terminal if they are logged in.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `write` command to send messages to a specific user instead of to everybody. You can send them over the network using whatever login credentials you already have, usually over ssh like this: `ssh youruse@hostname write username` to send username@hostname a message.

Comment: this opens up a connection to write message to the user, and I have to manually close the connection . How can I just open up a conncetion, send the message and close it. I want to write this inside a bash script

Comment: @Eular The same way you do for *any* STDIN stream in a shell. You can type a message and end it with CTRL-D, or pipe content to the command: `echo foo | ssh ...`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use nc for example
in receiving host type  `nc -l port_number` and in sending host type `nc ip port_number`  like

```
nc -l 3106
```

in receiving host and

```
nc 192.168.32.98 3106
```

in sending host for me that worked

Comment: "Terminal", not "TCP port".

Comment: but you can see this message in your terminal